# Removing Decimals in Power Map

Tags: excel, powerpivot

How can I get rid of the decimals for numbers (Circled in Blue) that appear in Power Map? I want the numbers to appear as 323,491 and 2,838,125.

[image]

I have tried changing the format in the Power Pivot window, the data source where the map pulls from, but I have had no luck. I have also tried changing the values to text, but this also doesn't work since an aggregation has to be performed on the numbers.

[image]

Creating an explicit measure as suggested by greggyb also did not work.

[image]

Comment: What if you use an explicit measure formatted as a whole number rather than an implicit measure that is created when you use a numeric column as a value in the report?

Comment: @greggyb Great idea. I really thought that was going to work! Still no luck though...  I've updated my question showing my attempt.

Comment: Are you particularly tied to Power Map as your visualization tool?

Comment: No. I've tried using Power View though and it doesn't seem to provide the functionality that Power Map does. Adding layers, the change the visualization to region option, etc.

Comment: This is indeed the case. Have you checked the newest version of Power View included as part of Power BI Desktop? It does include a filled map and custom visualizations are available. It might be worth checking out to see if it meets your needs. Import from a Power Pivot workbook in Excel is trivial, though Power Map reports would all need to be rebuilt. I suggest only because I see very little love coming for Power Map from Microsoft.

Comment: Sounds good. I do have Power BI on my desktop, but I haven't used it too much. I will give it a shot though and see what I can do.  Thanks for your help!